# getting integer value for win32 daemon state in windows and not getting current status

Tags: perl

I want to create and install a service which should run in background until it should not pause or stop from services.

So I created the following test script :

```
use Win32::Daemon;

my $ServicePath = 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe';
my $ServiceParams = 'C:\ila\bin\ilad.pl';

my %service_info = (
    name    => 'ilad',
    display => 'intelligent Lightweight Agent (ilad)',
    path    => $ServicePath,
    description => 'ilad',
    parameters => $ServiceParams,
    service_type => SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
    start_type => SERVICE_AUTO_START);

## create ilad service ##

if(Win32::Daemon::CreateService( \%service_info))
{
    print "successfully added \n";
}
else
{
    print "failed to add service: " . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::Daemon::GetLastError()); 
}

# Tell the OS to start processing the service...
Win32::Daemon::StartService(\%service_info))

print "Waiting...\n";
# Wait until the service manager is ready for us to continue...

print "SERVICE_NOT_READY " . SERVICE_NOT_READY . "\n";
print "SERVICE_STOPPED " . SERVICE_STOPPED . "\n";
print "SERVICE_RUNNING " . SERVICE_RUNNING . "\n";
print "SERVICE_PAUSED " . SERVICE_PAUSED . "\n";
print "SERVICE_START_PENDING " . SERVICE_START_PENDING . "\n";
print "SERVICE_STOP_PENDING " . SERVICE_STOP_PENDING . "\n";
print "SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING " . SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING . "\n";
print "SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING " . SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING . "\n";

while( SERVICE_START_PENDING != Win32::Daemon::State() )
{
    sleep( 1 );
    print Win32::Daemon::State() . "\n";
}
print "Running...\n";
# Now let the service manager know that we are running...
Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );

# Okay, go ahead and process stuff...
unlink( glob( "c:\\temp\\*.tmp" ) );

# Tell the OS that the service is terminating...
Win32::Daemon::StopService();
```

and I have this:

```
successfully added  
Waiting...  
SERVICE_NOT_READY 0  
SERVICE_STOPPED 1  
SERVICE_RUNNING 4  
SERVICE_PAUSED 7  
SERVICE_START_PENDING 2  
SERVICE_STOP_PENDING 3  
SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING 5  
SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING 6  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
1  
1  
1  
1  
1  
1  
Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

So it never reaches the SERVICE_RUNNING state and getting integer value and not getting current status of service.

I am using Strawberry perl. So anyone is having any idea?

Comment: What is the service parameter `C:\ila\bin\ilad.pl` ?

Comment: Note there is a syntax error on this line: `Win32::Daemon::StartService(\%service_info))` .There is one `)` too much and missing semicolon at the end

Comment: If I try to run this after fixing the syntax error above (and using a simple test script `ilad.pl`),  I get the following error: `failed to add service: Access is denied.`

Comment: I found out I need to run command prompt as admin, now it gives output a series of `1` as you describe

Comment: See also [Perl Windows Service- Only runs once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53934637/2173773)

Comment: Added a [related question](https://github.com/perl-libwin32/win32-daemon/issues/15) at the GitHub issue tracker..

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you think, the service does get run. The problem is that you're not looking at the output of the service.

You're executing code that should only be executed by the service (`StartService`) in your command-line script. This is wrong.

You're executing code that creates the service (`CreateService`) inside the service. This makes no sense.

Fixed:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw( $RealBin $RealScript );
use Win32::Daemon;

my $log_qfn = "C:\\Users\\ikegami\\a.log";
my $service_name = 'testtest';

sub logit {
   my ($msg) = @_;
   chomp($msg);

   open(my $fh, ">>", $log_qfn)
      or warn("Can't append to logit \"$log_qfn\": $!\n"), return;

   say $fh "[$$] $msg";
}

sub install_service {
   my %service_info = (
      name        => $service_name,
      display     => 'TESTTEST',
      description => 'TESTTESTTEST',
      path        => $^X,
      parameters  => qq{"$RealBin/$RealScript" service},
   );

   if (Win32::Daemon::CreateService(\%service_info)) {
      say "Successfully added.";
   } else {
      print "Failed to add service: " . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::Daemon::GetLastError()); 
   }
}


sub uninstall_service {
   if (Win32::Daemon::DeleteService("", $service_name)) {
      say "Successfully removed.";
   } else {
      print "Failed to remove service: " . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::Daemon::GetLastError()); 
   }
}


sub start_service {
   system("net", "start", "testtest");
}


sub service {
   logit("SERVICE_NOT_READY "        . SERVICE_NOT_READY);
   logit("SERVICE_STOPPED "          . SERVICE_STOPPED);
   logit("SERVICE_RUNNING "          . SERVICE_RUNNING);
   logit("SERVICE_PAUSED "           . SERVICE_PAUSED);
   logit("SERVICE_START_PENDING "    . SERVICE_START_PENDING);
   logit("SERVICE_STOP_PENDING "     . SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
   logit("SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING " . SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING);
   logit("SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING "    . SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING);

   logit("state = " . Win32::Daemon::State());

   Win32::Daemon::StartService();

   logit("Waiting");
   while (1) {
      my $state = Win32::Daemon::State();
      logit("state = $state");
      last if $state == SERVICE_START_PENDING;
      sleep(1);
   }

   logit("Running");
   Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
   logit("state = " . Win32::Daemon::State());

   logit("This is the service doing stuff.");

   logit("Stopping");
   Win32::Daemon::StopService();
   logit("state = " . Win32::Daemon::State());
}


{
   @ARGV == 1
      or die("usage\n");

   my $cmd = shift(@ARGV);
   logit($cmd);
   if    ( $cmd eq 'install'   ) { install_service();   }
   elsif ( $cmd eq 'uninstall' ) { uninstall_service(); }
   elsif ( $cmd eq 'start'     ) { start_service();     }
   elsif ( $cmd eq 'service'   ) { service();           }
   else {
      die("usage\n");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\ikegami>a.pl install
Successfully added.

C:\Users\ikegami>type a.log
[40952] install

C:\Users\ikegami>wmic Service WHERE Name="testtest" GET Name, PathName
Name      PathName
testtest  C:\progs\sp5302-x64\perl\bin\perl.exe "C:/Users/ikegami\a.pl" service

C:\Users\ikegami>a.pl start
The TESTTEST service is starting..
The TESTTEST service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.


C:\Users\ikegami>type a.log
[40952] install
[28480] start
[39880] service
[39880] SERVICE_NOT_READY 0
[39880] SERVICE_STOPPED 1
[39880] SERVICE_RUNNING 4
[39880] SERVICE_PAUSED 7
[39880] SERVICE_START_PENDING 2
[39880] SERVICE_STOP_PENDING 3
[39880] SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING 5
[39880] SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING 6
[39880] state = 0
[39880] Waiting
[39880] state = 0
[39880] state = 2
[39880] Running
[39880] state = 4
[39880] This is the service doing stuff.
[39880] Stopping
[39880] state = 1

C:\Users\ikegami>a.pl uninstall
Successfully removed.
```

I know it `net start` says the service wasn't started, but the log clearly shows it was, so ignore that message. The service (intentionally) stopped so soon after starting that `net start` didn't notice or presumes a failure.

A lot of improvements can be made.

- Logging messages [to the event viewer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::EventLog) instead of some arbitrary log file.
- Cleanly stop the service on exception.
- Using callbacks as shown in Example 5 of the documentation.
- Find some way of starting the service without using `net start`. Maybe Win32::Daemon is capable of that. If so, use that. If not, add support to it!

Comment: Great example this answers most of my questions! One small thing: I wonder if there is any difference between using `FindBin` and `Win32::GetFullPathName($0)` to get the working directory of the script?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, FindBin will work on other systems. I don't know how either handles stuff akin to links on Windows. You could maybe post a self-answered question about their interactions with symlinks (Win32::Symlink) hard links (Win32::Hardlink) and junctions (if that's something different). Two types of tests are needed: link to a directory in the path, and link to the script itself.

Comment: Another issue I discovered: If I try to stop a service by running `net stop my_service` I am not able to stop  it. I get error: `The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2191.`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Using the callback approach from Example 5 of the docs (as I mentioned should be done) should resolve that

Comment: How can I stop or pause this service through service-menu?

Comment: @ikegami Added [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62674009/2173773) regarding stopping the service

Comment: I tried to use Acceptedcontrols but it’s not working. Not getting stop and pause option in service menu.

Comment: @IshikaGoel *"How can I stop or pause this service through service-menu?"* It was a bug in the module. [Her is a fix](https://github.com/perl-libwin32/win32-daemon/pull/16). Can you try it and see if it works?