# How to stop a Win32 service started with Win32::Daemon?

Tags: perl, winapi, windows-services

I am able to start a Win32 service successfully on Windows 10 (Strawberry perl version 5.30.1) using the follwing script:

```
package Win32::XYZService;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use Win32;
use Win32::Daemon;

{
    die "Bad arguments" if @ARGV != 1;
    my $action = shift @ARGV;
    my $xyz = Win32::XYZService->new();
    $xyz->action( $action );

}

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
    $args{name} = 'xyz_service2';
    my ($bin, $scriptname) = Win32::GetFullPathName( $0 );
    $args{bin} = $bin;
    $args{scriptname} = $scriptname;
    $args{log_fn} = File::Spec->catfile( $bin, 'log.txt' );
    $args{time_interval} = 2000;  # callback timer interval in milliseconds
    my $self = bless \%args, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub action {
    my ($self, $action) = @_;

    if ($self->can($action)) {
        return $self->$action();
    }
    else {
        $self->log("Unknown command: $action");
        $self->log("Valid commands are: create, start, stop, delete");
        return undef;
    }
}

sub start {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->log("starting service..");
    system("net", "start", $self->{name});
}

sub stop {
    my ($self) = @_;

    $self->log("trying to stop service..");
    system("net", "stop", $self->{name});
}

sub _scm_start {
    my ($self) = @_;

    Win32::Daemon::RegisterCallbacks( {
        start       =>  \&_callback_start,
        timer       =>  \&_callback_timer,
        stop        =>  \&_callback_stop,
        pause       =>  \&_callback_pause,
        continue    =>  \&_callback_continue,
    } );
    Win32::Daemon::StartService( $self, $self->{time_interval} );
}

sub _callback_continue {
    my ( $event, $self) = @_;

    $self->log("callback continue");
    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
}

sub _callback_pause {
    my ( $event, $self) = @_;

    $self->log("callback pause");
    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_PAUSED );
}

sub _callback_stop {
    my ( $event, $self) = @_;

    $self->log("callback stop");
    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_STOPPED );
    Win32::Daemon::StopService();
}

sub _callback_timer {
    my ( $event, $self) = @_;

    $self->log("callback timer");
}

sub _callback_start {
    my ( $event, $self) = @_;

    $self->log("callback start");
    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
}

sub log {
    my ($self, $msg) = @_;

    chomp $msg;
    open(my $fh, ">>", $self->{log_fn})
        or warn("Can't append to log \"$self->{log_fn}\": $!\n"), return;
    say $fh "[PID $$] [" . localtime . "] : $msg";
    say $msg if -t STDIN;
}

sub delete {
    my ($self) = @_;
    if (Win32::Daemon::DeleteService("", $self->{name})) {
        $self->log("Successfully removed service $self->{name}");
    }
    else {
        $self->log("Failed to remove service: " . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::Daemon::GetLastError()));
    }
}

sub create {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $service_path = $^X;
    my $service_params = File::Spec->catfile($self->{bin}, $self->{scriptname});
    $service_params .= ' _scm_start';  # Service control manager start
    my %service_info = (
        name            => $self->{name},
        display         => 'xyz_display',
        path            => $service_path,
        description     => 'xyz_description',
        parameters      => $service_params,
        service_type    => SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        start_type      => SERVICE_AUTO_START
    );

    if (Win32::Daemon::CreateService( \%service_info)) {
        $self->log("Successfully added service $service_info{name}");
    }
    else {
        $self->log("Failed to add service: " . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::Daemon::GetLastError()));
    }
}
```

If I run this script from command prompt as admin:

```
>perl xyz_service.pl create
Successfully added service xyz_service2

>perl xyz_service.pl start
starting service..
The xyz_display service is starting.
The xyz_display service was started successfully.

>type log.txt
[PID 8844] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:05 2020] : Successfully added service xyz_service2
[PID 10552] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:42 2020] : starting service..
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:42 2020] : callback start
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:44 2020] : callback timer
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:46 2020] : callback timer
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:48 2020] : callback timer
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:50 2020] : callback timer
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:52 2020] : callback timer
[PID 12076] [Wed Jul  1 11:33:54 2020] : callback timer

>perl xyz_service.pl stop
stopping service..
The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2191.
```

How can I stop the service?

Comment: Use Windows UI or "net stop [service name]" command line: https://www.isumsoft.com/computer/3-ways-to-start-a-service-in-windows.html this will call back into your _callback_stop method. In fact, once your service is registered, you aren't suppose to use perl command to start, resume, pause, etc. but Windows UI or command line or even Windows APIs

Comment: @SimonMourier I just used `net stop` in my question above. When I use the windows "Services" app, and right-click on the service name, the `Stop` action is grayed out, so it is not possible to stop it

Comment: I hadn't seen. If you can't stop it it means it's either not properly registered and/or it doesn't answer to stop commands

Comment: From what I can tell so far, it's not something passed to [`CreateService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicew); it's something passed using [`SetServiceStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setservicestatus), and Win32::Daemon doesn't provide an interface for that.

Comment: Actually, `Win32::Daemon::State` ends up calling `SetServiceStatus`, but it doesn't set the relevant field (`dwControlsAccepted`), much less provide a means of specifying a value for it.

Comment: Check the service status in the windows "Services" app to see if it is running. If yes, you can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) tool via right click the service -> properties -> Services -> Permissions to see if you have permissions.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT, This isn't a permission issue

Comment: @ikegami *"Win32::Daemon::State ends up calling SetServiceStatus"* I grepped through the [source code](https://metacpan.org/source/XENU/Win32-Daemon-20190315) but I could not find any call to `SetServiceStatus`

Comment: @ ikegami Sorry, I found it `ServiceThread.cpp` line 452

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, You could use Win32::API to call `SetServiceStatus` instead of using W::D's wrapper, but 1) that might cause problems if you use W::D' timer feature, and 2) `SetServiceStatus` is called all over the place in W::D, so I think the the flags you set by calling it directly risk getting cleared. /// As such, I think a change to W::D is required.

Comment: @ikegami I also found an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/stopping-a-service) which uses `ControlService()` to stop the service

Comment: That's surely what the Services app and `net stop` use. So while the linked document shows how to stop a service without shelling out to execute `net stop`, I don't think it's going to help resolve your problem.

Comment: @ikegami I think the problem is in `DllMan()` at [line 959](https://metacpan.org/source/XENU/Win32-Daemon-20190315/Daemon.xs#L959). It only checks `dwMajorVersion` up to version 6, but Windows 10 will give a value of 10, so `gdwControlsAccepted` is set to zero (the default value) meaning that the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` bit will not be set..

Comment: oh, I assumed that `CleanStatusStruct` just zeroed out the struct or whatever, and I never went back to verify. You have indeed found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is supposed to use [`SetServiceStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setservicestatus) to signal to Windows that it can handle shutdown events. And it does so in older versions of Windows. However, it fails to do that in Windows 10 (and newer) and Windows Server 2016 (and newer).

This failure is the result of the lack of a default clause in a [`switch` statement](https://metacpan.org/source/XENU/Win32-Daemon-20190315/Daemon.xs#L959) in the module's `DllMain` in `Demon.xs`. As a result of this problem, `gdwControlsAccepted` ends up with an incorrect value.

The corrected `switch`:

```c
            switch( gsOSVerInfo.dwMajorVersion )
            {
                default:
                    // We have Windows Vista or newer
                    //  The following constants only work on Vista and higher:
                    //      SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN
                    //
#ifdef SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN
                    gdwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;
#endif  // SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN

                case 5:
                    // We have Windows 2000 or XP
                    //  The following constants only work on Win2k and higher:
                    //      SERVICE_ACCEPT_PARAMCHANGE
                    //      SERVICE_ACCEPT_NETBINDCHANGE
                    //
                    gdwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_PARAMCHANGE  
                                        |  SERVICE_ACCEPT_NETBINDCHANGE;

                case 4:
                case 3:
                case 2:
                case 1:
                case 0:
                    // NT 4.0
                    gdwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP 
                                        |  SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE
                                        |  SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
            }
```

I have not tested this. Please test and file bug report.

Comment: With the help of @Håkon Hægland

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/perl-libwin32/win32-daemon/pull/16)

Comment: Oh I did not see that you had a better version of the ordering of the switch statement.. maybe I will rewrite it later

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, My code was wrong --Fixed!-- but there's a way simpler solution that yours nonetheless